# i want to execute .exe from a button using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans6.8

i want to open another program which is not in windows path. 
below are code to open notepad which is in windows path.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /C start notepad" );
```

and i want to open an exe file from the path below:

```
C:\Users\midi\Documents\Downloads\Compressed\ARToolKit-2.72.1-bin-win32\ARToolKit\bin
```

please help me. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the executable is called "Executable.exe" it should simply be

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\Users\\midi\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\ARToolKit-2.72.1-bin-win32\\ARToolKit\\bin\\Executable.exe" );
```

If it's a wise decision to hardcode the absolute path is another question.

Answer (score 2):

You have the code to execute executables right there. All you need to do is escape the slashes in the path.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\midi\\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\ARToolKit-2.72.1-bin-win32\\ARToolKit\\bin");
```

Comment: While creating the process this gives me an error because of missing rights (Win7, Java 7).

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works create a batch file using notepad and renaming it to someName.bat.For your question it should be as below;

```
@echo on
cd C:\Users\midi\Documents\Downloads\Compressed\ARToolKit-2.72.1-bin-win32\ARToolKit\bin 
run cnext
```

Then supposing the bat file is on the desktop include the code below behind button click listener.

```
  try {
                Process pr=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\Labuser\\Desktop\\someName.bat");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```